# What is the best page ordering plugin that works well with WPML?

Tags: plugins, pages, multi-language, hierarchical

The title says it all.

What is the best page ordering plugin that works well with WPML? It seems that may are reporting issues with different plugins such as my page order and WPML page order.

WordPress 3.1 RC3
WPML 2.0.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far the best plugin that I have tested to order pages by language is CMS Tree Page View.
It allows you to select the language in which to order pages. Ordering is done in a drag and drop tree view.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-tree-page-view/

Comment: Looks like this plugin has just been updated and it works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I always use Post Types Order which provides a simple drag n drop ordering 
Check it out http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-types-order/

Comment: Does it work with hierarchical posts?

Answer (score 2):

It is also important to note these two things:

- if you are using custom types, make sure that `page-attributes` is enabled;
- if you want to have different order for different languages, make sure that in `WPML/Translation Management/Multilingual Content Setup` option `Synchronize page order for translations` is disabled.

As for a plugin, I've been using [Simple Page Ordering](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-page-ordering/), which is working great.

Answer (score 0):

CMS Tree Page View does support WPML, but not for custom post types.
It doesn't show the languages link and ordering posts works only for the default language: translated languages doesn't keep the order.

It also appears that this plugin isn't much maintained: I can't find anywhere to download it, but I have it installed in a multi language, from I don't remember where.

Would be nice to know some other alternatives: anyone?